# Calculate the vertices of a triangle from the center point?

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on a programming assignment, and there's a part where I don't understand the 'mathematics' behind it.

I am given a triangle with 3 vertices, with the coordinates: (0,0), (1, 0), (0,-1).

What I got so far:

1. The area is 0.5
2. The perimeter is 3.4142
3. The center point is (0.333,-0.333) Edited to include the negative sign.

Now, I take the center point, and move it to (0,0). The challenge for me is to find the new vertices of the triangle. This is where I'm stuck. I know that the triangle won't always be equilateral.

Comment: `3.The center point is (0.333,0.333)` The centroid can't be above the $x$ axis, since the entire triangle is below it. `Now, I take the center point, and move it to (0,0)` That moves the centroid left by $1/3$ and up by $1/3\,$. Do the same with the other points. `I know that the triangle won't always be equilateral` This triangle you used as an example is certainly not equilateral.

Comment: The center point is outside the triangle, and the triangle isn't equilateral. You might want to edit your question a bit.

Comment: According to this wonderful resource (http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) there are at least a thousand points that may be called *center* of a triangle. Which one are you considering?

Comment: This is for a programming assignment. I mentioned that the triangle won't always be equilateral because the 'tester' program our instructor will use for grading will be different points each time. I did some searching around on the site for questions like mine, and they were all about equilateral triangles. I used the above coordinates as an example to go by. The center point is where (x1+x2+x3)/3, (y1+ y2+y3)/3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire triangle is below the $x$-axis, so your center is $(1/3,-1/3)$.
If you move the center, you need to add $(-1/3,1/3)$ to every coordinate. I assume that you don't rotate the triangle, so the new coordinates are $(-1/3,1/3)$, $(2/3,1/3)$, $(-1/3,-2/3)$

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me.